# How to open a specific page with a Toast notification?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a `Toast` notification here as shown, and with the method `Launch ()`, I am assigning the character '1' to it :

```
  IToastImageAndText02 toastEng = ToastContentFactory.CreateToastImageAndText02();
    toastEng.TextHeading.Lang = "en";
    toastEng.TextHeading.Text = "1st Sunday of the month";
    toastEng.TextBodyWrap.Text = "Free admission to museums!";
    toastEng.Launch = "1";
```

The thing that I want to know here is how do I open a particular page after I press the notification on the screen. Also, where should I put the character '1' ?

Guidance and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When a user taps a toast notification, the app get's *launched* and the App(.xaml.cs) OnLaunched is executed.

Only thing you can to there is read the Launch paramter from the provided EventArgs and decide if you want to navigate somewhere.

As the Launch parameter is the only thing you can send, I recommend putting Json (or another serialized format) in there to get multiple values.

Comment: `if (e.Arguments == "1")
                {
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageDomenicaGratis));
                }` is the correct way?